# Getline ignoring first character while using cin.ignore()

Tags: c++, oop, structure, getline, c-strings

I am trying to enter information into a structure such as name, address, contact number, etc. but what happens is that the first character of the name of the first employee is erased but the other employees have complete names

```
    void input(){
        char ans;
        int i=0;
        int x=1;
        char num[2];
        char temp1[5] = "E0";
        char id1[5] = "E0";


        do{
            system ("cls");
            if (x<10){
                strncpy(temp1,id1,1);
            }

            cout<< "Employee Number: " << temp1 << x;
            itoa(x,num,10);
            strcat (temp1,num);
            strcpy(emp[i].num,temp1);
            cout<< endl;
            cout<< "Name: ";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(emp[i].name,99);
            cout<<"Address: ";  
            cin.getline(emp[i].add, 99);
            cout<<"Contact Number: ";
            cin>> emp[i].connum; 
            cout<<"Department: ";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.getline(emp[i].dept,99);
            cout<<"Position: ";
            cin.getline(emp[i].pos,99);
            cout<<"Date Started: ";
            cin>> emp[i].date;
            cout<<"Rate per Day: ";
            cin>>emp[i].rateperd;
            cout<< fixed << setprecision(2);
            cout<<"Rate per Hour: ";
            emp[i].rateperh=emp[i].rateperd/8;
            cout<<emp[i].rateperh<<endl;
            cout<<"Overtime Rate: ";
            emp[i].otrate=emp[i].rateperh*1.5;
            cout<< emp[i].otrate<<endl;
            i++;
            x++;
            strcpy(temp1,id1);
            cout<< "Would you like to ADD another EMPLOEE (Y/N)?";
            cin>> ans;
        }while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');
    }
```

Comment: `cin.ignore();` ignores a character.

Comment: Move `cin.ignore();` from where it currently is to after `cin >> ans`